# Command not found when installing from vsix

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to build the vsix for my project vscode-atlasmap locally from this branch https://github.com/apupier/vscode-atlasmap/tree/36-useWebiewAPI

When I launch the debug instance, it is working fine. If i build the vsix, install it and then try to use the "Open AtlasMap" I have an error message "command 'atlasmap.start' not found"

I got a message that the extension has been successfully installed.

The mentioned command is listed in the "Contributions":
[image]

What could be the issue? What is different from "Debug configuration" and a built vsix?

regards,

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that all of your dependencies are installed via

```
node install
```

before packaging. Note that vsce will only install those mentioned in your package.json.

When I had this problem, I moved extend, request, and underscore from devDependencies to dependences. Then I ran

```
node install
```

and then

```
vsce package
```

again.

To retry, make sure you uninstall the old version of your package, and that you remove the package from wherever it is installed (for me in .vscode/extensions),

Comment: Thanks Eric.

I tried to clean node_modules, call npm run clean, checked that the extension was removed from .vscode/extensions then redo:  

- npm install --ignore-scripts  
- npm install  
- npm run compile  
- vsce package  
- install from VSIX... in a VS Code instance  
  
I still have the same problem.  

I checked the devDependencies but found nothing strange. i would expect also the IDE to complain if I have something in the right place.

Comment: It turned out that the dependencies and devDependencies in the package.json where not matching fully what was used inside the extension. After adding the missing ones the commands worked fine.

Comment: For me, I somehow included `**/node_modules` in `.vscodeignore`. I just removed it and now it works.